# functionality of del statement

Tags: python, string, split, del

I wonder why if I split a string with multiple characters into a list, then `del` function works only if I save the list into a new object?
Example:

```py
x = 'Hello world'
del x.split()[0]
print(x)
out: Hello world
```

```py
y = x.split()
del y[0]
print(y)
out: ['world']
```

Comment: @Matthias sorry, updated

Comment: You can not change a str, they are "immutable". You can change a list, the are "mutable". The statement `del x.split()[0]` first creates a list, then it deletes the first element in the list, then the list is forgotten because there is no reference to it. EDIT: uhm, yeah what Chepner said in his answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, `x.split()` creates a list that is entirely independent of `x` (even ignoring the fact that `str` values are immutable); modifying that list won't affect `x` in any way.

Second, you didn't save a reference to the list returned by `x.split()`, so even though `del x.split()[0]` does mutate that list, once the statement completes, the *entire* list is subject to garbage collection.

In your second example, you *do*  have a reference t the return value of `x.split(0)`, so you can observe the result of `del`.